# Applying a function a list using llply - how to deal with non-conforming entries?

Tags: r, plyr, data-manipulation

I have this function, which runs fine (on this [data](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/ea77c4c9f6694342b3e5)):

```
library(plyr)
library(network)

makeNetworkGraph <- function(graph_object){
  output <- as.network(graph_object[, 3:4])
  (output)
 }
```

However, as soon as I try to apply it to multiple objects in a list (data is [here](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/ea210c858d3839d6bf01)):

```
graph_objects <- llply(graph_list, makeNetworkGraph)
```

It fails miserably:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(graph_list, , 3:4) : undefined columns selected
```

What is going on here? It seems to be caused by some entries in the list essentially being empty (but not `NULL`):

```
$`809`
[1] id
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Is it possibly have `llply` simply skip over entries in the list which generate errors, leave a `NULL` and move to the next entry? It seems as if `llply` completely stops unless it can apply the supplied function properly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed it is possible - `plyr` makes this very easy. Your code would look something like:

```
library(plyr)

res <- llply(graph_list, failwith(NULL, makeNetworkGraph))

# see the index of elements which have failed
which(vapply(res, is.null, logical(1)))

# remove NULL entries
res <- compact(NULL)
```

Hope this helps :)